# Facebook box count not going up

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-like

http://www.sonikastudios.com/blog/company-news/real-estate-website-design-development-vancouver/

So I got the same code installed for this post as the other posts I have. No matter how many different friends LIKE the post, I can't seem to get the # going. I'm using Wordpress, so it's the same template files. single.php, and loop.php has the exact same code. you can see other posts at:

http://www.sonikastudios.com/blog/

Other posts below, as you can see, have as many as 30+ likes in the count.

Is this a simple issue of caching on Facebook's part? Or am I missing something?

Here's my code:

```
<body>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and on loop.php or single.php:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {"requires_login":false,"error_info":{"brief":"No
>   administrators were specified.","full":"The page failed to provide a
>   valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators
>   using either a \"fb:app_id\" meta tag, or using a \"fb:admins\" meta
>   tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook
>   users."}

This was the error I see when liking your page.

So I linted the page at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sonikastudios.com%2Fblog%2Fcompany-news%2Freal-estate-website-design-development-vancouver%2F and this is what I see there

> **Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
>   *Inferred Property*:  fb:admins and fb:app_id missing. fb:admins or fb:app_id is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that
>   generates a high clickthrough rate.
>   **Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
>   *Inferred Property*:  The og:description property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Fix those things and I think you'll be back in business!!  :)

Comment: Those are warnings, won't stop the count. Besides, there are many other pages in the same blog with no different code that get the counts up. Any way, I tried it and it still does not work.

Comment: Fixed it. When I tried the LIKE button on the Facebook like button generator page, it returned the error: "There were problems uploading "http://new.sonikastudios.com/images/sonika_logo_square_small.png" on behalf of your Open Graph page. Here is the full error message our photo server reported: "The image URL leads to an empty file.""   I had forgotten to remove the new. subdomain!!! Silly me.

Comment: Looks like you fixed the og warnings. (linter tool reports back without those errors).  Congrats!!  Also I can go to the site and like the page without the error showing up in the network traffic.  Contrats!!  Looks like with the correct fb:admins and fb:app_id being specified helped!!

Comment: OK I'm totally confused about this. When I add the fb admin IDs, it works. but then now it creates an actual PAGE on Facebook!! I don't want this to be a page in its own. How does this work? I had this issue with a site once, and I deleted all OG tags - then it came back to normal, where the LIKES were for the URL only without creating a FB page entity.

Comment: For how it works questions, you should ask that question at http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbDevelopers.  On Stackoverflow, we're more about how to get the code to work, not necessarily how things work the way they do. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I sorted it out - turns out any OG graph tags is MEANT to convert the LIKE to a page entity. Could be useful for tracking likes on a main domain. However, if you omit it, and use the image_src meta tag, then you can define a main thumbnail without turning it into a Facebook Page upon liking a URL! Useful tip for blog pages etc.